# adobe flash ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: flash, video-streaming

ubuntu 12.04 LTS.   Flash videos played then stopped playing about a year ago.  How can I check to see what crashes and what needs to be REMOVEd and reINSTALLed?

Comment: Did you try re-installing `ubuntu-restricted-extras`?

Comment: What version of flash-player are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Open Synaptic and reinstall flashplugin-installer.
Also reinstall libquvi-scripts and libquvi7.
This should give you the latest version and correct your troubles
unless your browser is interfering in some way with flash.
Have you checked to see if you have any flash block addons or
extensions that disable flash?

Comment: Please explain why OP should **reinstall** "libquvi-scripts and libquvi7" when OP has a problem with Flash itself. I'm tempted to downvote this answer.